# Convert JFIF files to JPEG in python

Tags: python

I have a folder of folders with JFIF photos and I need to convert them all to JPEG format, I think the problem is coming from either my if statement because there are other photos in the folders that do not need to be converted or the for loop. Thank you

```
from PIL import Image
import os

root = r"(my computer path to the folder)"

count = 0
for dirs, subdir, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        lastChar = file[-1:]
        if(lastChar == 'f'):
            img = Image.open(file)
            #file ends in .jfif, remove 4 characters
            fileName = file[:-4]
            #add jpg and save
            img.save(fileName + "jpg")
```

I am getting this error right now,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'IMG_4242_1615254307.jfif'

Comment: `img = Image.open(file)` - this will look for `file` in CWD, not in `dirs` folder

Comment: @buran I wonder if `glob` would work better for this?

Comment: I think you can just rename your files from `.jfif` to `.jpg` without reading them, decompressing them and recompressing them and potentially taking ages and reducing the quality. Maybe try renaming one.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
import os

root = r"my computer path to the folder"
print(root)
count = 0
for dirs, subdir, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        lastChar = file[-4:]
        if(lastChar == 'jfif'):
            img = Image.open(root+'\\'+file)
            #file ends in .jfif, remove 4 characters
            fileName = file[:-4]
            print(fileName)
            #add jpg and save
            img.save(root+'\\'+fileName + "jpg")
```

Comment: Please edit your code formatting. Also Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
import os

root = r"my computer path to the folder"
print(root)
count = 0
for dirs, subdir, files in os.walk(root):
    for file in files:
        lastChar = file[-4:]
        if(lastChar == 'jfif'):
            img = Image.open(dirs+'\\'+file)
            #file ends in .jfif, remove 4 characters
            fileName = file[:-4]
            print(fileName)
            #add jpg and save
            img.save(dirs+'\\'+fileName + "jpg")
```